# How do I np.sqrt the first column in a an array while leaving the second alone?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to square root the entire first column while leaving the second column alone. This is my current array.
`Q14 = Q13.copy`
OUTPUT BELOW:

```
array([[124609.,    349.],
       [ 46225.,    228.],
       [ 50176.,    215.],
       ...,
       [ 51984.,    224.],
       [ 46225.,    228.],
       [ 50176.,    215.]])
```

The array is a `(406080, 2)`.
I have tried `Q14 = np.sqrt(Q14[:,0])`

and I get the error

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed.
```

I believe this is a 2-D array, so not sure why this error is coming up. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To only update one column, you would want to do `Q14[:,0] = np.sqrt(Q14[:,0])`. Which line is the error actually on? If you perform the operation you show, you turn `Q14` into a 1D array, so later 2D indexing will throw this error.

Comment: I just tried what you suggested and I am getting invalid value in sqrt error

Comment: Are your numbers all ints or floats? Do you have any negative numbers?

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

From your sample:

```
In [24]: data = np.array([[124609.,    349.], [ 46225.,    228.], [ 50176.,    215.], [ 51984.,    224.], [ 46225.,    228.], [ 50176.,    215.]])
```

double check the shape:

```
In [25]: data.shape
Out[25]: (6, 2)

In [26]: data
Out[26]: 
array([[124609.,    349.],
       [ 46225.,    228.],
       [ 50176.,    215.],
       [ 51984.,    224.],
       [ 46225.,    228.],
       [ 50176.,    215.]])
```

Apply the sqrt to first column:

```
In [27]: data[:,0] = np.sqrt(data[:,0])

In [28]: data
Out[28]: 
array([[353., 349.],
       [215., 228.],
       [224., 215.],
       [228., 224.],
       [215., 228.],
       [224., 215.]])
```

If you get errors that go against what believe, `I believe this is a 2-D array`, double check that belief.  Don't assume - verify;

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work. I get "invalid value in sqrt" error. I verified it an it is a (406080,2) array.

Comment: What's the array's `dtype`

Comment: Is this an actual error, or (just) as run time warning?  Give us some real information about the problems, not just short summaries.  If you want help, give us as much debugging information as you can, not the least amount!

Comment: With this many rows it will be up to you to identify the problem values.  That's far too many to share with us.  I shown what can work if the values are good.